# How can I keep my putty scrollback buffer when using emacs -nw and gnu screen?

Tags: emacs, putty, gnu-screen

Here's my problem - hopefully I can explain this well enough:

I use Putty on Windows, and then start a gnu screen session.  I may run several shell commands in putty, and then in the same screen, run emacs -nw.  The problem is that when I exit emacs, the scrollback buffer (in putty) is messed up.  What was on the screen when I started emacs is gone, and if I scroll upward I see various artifacts of screen (e.g. the screen "bar" at the bottom, etc.).

If I don't use screen and just open emacs -nw directly from putty, all my history is still there in the buffer when I exit emacs.

Likewise, if I do use screen, and use vi within a screen instead of emacs, when I exit vi, everything is there.

Is this just some weird interaction with putty and emacs?  Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: `screen`, of course, has its own scrollback feature. Ctrl-a esc.

Comment: Yes - when I use that, all the history is completely gone.  So I can see a little of it if I scroll up using the mouse wheel or bar on the right, or none of it if I scroll up using screen's scrollback (I can just scroll up forever and everything is blank).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting scrollback buffer size to something else than default? [scrollback](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Scrollback.html)

In .screenrc put this line:

```
defscrollback 10000
```

Here's my config .screenrc. Tried to reproduce this problem but no luck... you can try if it fixes for you:

```
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
startup_message off
vbell off
autodetach on
altscreen on
shelltitle "$ |bash"
defscrollback 10000
defutf8 on
nonblock on

hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kw}[ %{= kb}%H%{= kw} ][%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{= kW}%n*%f %t%?%?%{= kw}%?%+Lw%?%?%= ][ %{r}%l%{w} ]%{w}[%{r} %d/%m/%y %C %A %{w}]%{w}'

bind 'q' quit
```

Just at the end I would as well suggest you getting familiar with tmux -> http://tmux.sourceforge.net/

BTW. hopefully you're using newest version of PuTTy right? :) - > http://puttytray.goeswhere.com/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Emacs and Screen are stepping on each others toes over the alternate screen feature of your terminal.

I cannot reproduce this issue, but maybe putting the following in your ~/.screenrc would help:

```
altscreen on
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) as an alternative to GNU screen?

Comment: I've heard good things about it, but for one, it's not installed at work - I could probably get them to do it, but then I'd be learning something entirely new (biggest concern is the muscle memory of window switching, splitting windows, etc.) when I'm perfectly happy with screen aside from this issue.

Comment: Fair enough. Minimally you could ask for tmux to be installed just so you can quickly try out whether it solves your issue, and if it doesn't you don't even have to think about switching.